# How do you do wildcard searches with Mongoid in a Ruby on Rails environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, mongodb, mongoid

The Mongoid documentation only gives one example of doing a wildcard search:

```
Person.where(first_name: /^d/i)
```

This finds all people with the first name that starts with "d".

What do the `/^` and `/i` represent?

How do I find all people with their first name having an "na" in the middle of the string? E.g., this query would find "jonathan" since "na" is a substring of the entire string.

Is there website or guide with this information?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need this to find people with "na" in the name.

```
Person.where(first_name: /na/i)
```

As for your example:

```
Person.where(first_name: /^d/i)
```

`^` means "beginning of the line". This regex will match all strings where first letter is "d". `/i` means "do case-insensitive matches". So it'll match both "d" and "D".

**Note**: only prefix regexes (with `^` in front) are able to use indexes.

> Is there website or guide with this information?

Here's [my favourite](http://rubular.com).

Comment: Is it possible to do query like `Person.where(first_name: /na/i)` if the field `first_name` is of type `Mongoid::EncryptedString`. I am using mongoid 3.1.6 and getting *TypeError: no implicit conversion of Regexp into String*.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh, not directly unfortunately.

You can iterate through the whole data-set though, something like `Person.all.select { |p| p.first_name ~= /na/i }`, which is obviously less efficient.

Answer (score 7):

This is not a "wildcard" search, this is called a regular expression.

```
/^d/i
```

- The two slashes are only the regex delimiters, you search for what is in between those two slashes.
- The following `i` is a modifier or option. It changes the matching behaviour of your regex, the `i` stands for case insensitive, means it matches "d" and "D".
- The first character `^` is an anchor, it anchors the search pattern to the start of the string, means match "d" only at the start of the string

A good tutorial about regular expressions is the [tutorial on regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)

If you want to search for a string anywhere in the string, just remove the anchor that binds the pattern to the start, `/na/` will find "na" anywhere in the string.